# Getting computer name, computer's Local ip and computer's server ip using php

Tags: php

How do I get computer name, computer's Local IP (if it is using LAN) and computer's server IP (LAN's Server IP) using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server IP: `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`

Computer name: You **can't** get that.

Local ip will be `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` if you are on a local server.

**This is the list of available** `$_SERVER` vars: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I think Server IP: $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] will give us the IP of server which is actually executing the PHP script. am I right??? If yes then I don't need that, I need LAN's server IP.

Comment: server on LAN to which my system is connected

Answer (score 1):

I think they should all be in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

All covered here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

I use this one:

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```